# CSS Overflow-x: hidden in animation working on chrome but not safari

Tags: html, css, animation, overflow

I have an animation that slides in a bar with a few dropdown menus from left to right by just growing the container from 0 to 660px.
I didn't make this myself, but this is the way it looked when I startetd working on it:

```
    @keyframes fadeIn-animation {
        from {overflow-x: hidden; max-width: 0}
        to {overflow-x: hidden; max-width: 660px}
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn-animation {
        from {overflow-x: hidden; max-width: 0}
        to {overflow-x: hidden; max-width: 660px}
    }
    .animated-container {
        animation-name: fadeIn-animation;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn-animation;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
```

This works fine on chrome but not on safari.

The part of the animation with the container growing from 0 to 660 px works but all the child elements are already visible during the transition because of the overflow being visible. https://jsfiddle.net/6cqapbnu/

I tried setting the bar element to

```
overflow-x: hidden; 
overflow-y: visible;
```

instead of having those in the animation,
which makes the animation work correctly but now the dropdowns don't overflow correctly, they are scrollable.

I read somewhere that this is because when you set `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` to `visible` and the other one to **something different** than `visible` the `visible` is handled like `auto` 
 I don't know if that's true or still the case though.

I think the easier solution would be to just have the `overflow-x: hidden` work correctly within the animation like it does on chrome.

How can I fix this?

Comment: overflow: auto; might help you.

Comment: This just adds a scrollbar when I try it.

Answer (score -1):

You should check browser compatibility of attributes before using them.
You can use 
https://caniuse.com/
to check.

Comment: And which attribute I am using is not compatible?
As far as I see it: the `overflow-x: hidden` works when I use directly on the animated-container. 
It just messes with the overflow-y as well (on both chrome and safari btw) that's why this doesn't solve our problem.
It however does not work anymore when I use it only within the animation keyframe (only on safari).